# What are the different worlds being shown in “Justice League: Warworld?”

Tags: dc, justice-league, justice-league-warworld

In the animated movie *Justice League: Warworld* there are 3 different worlds are shown:

> These worlds were created by Martian Manhunter as a projection.
>
> One is the wild west Jonah Hex world, another is a world of Warlord, and the third is a black-and-white world.

Where do these worlds relate to in comics, or are they created solely for the purpose of the movie?

Answer (score 1):

The Jonah Hex world is most likely a throwback to [the similarly named comic character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah_Hex), who is an antihero who lived during the "cowboy" time period.

[image: A drawing of Jonah Hex. He is somewhat of a cliché cowboy character, with big coat, dirty clothing, leather boots, a hat, and two revolvers. A defining characteristic of Jonah Hex is also his disfigured face.]

The world of Warlord, on the other hand, would be for [the similarly named character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlord_(DC_Comics)), which according to Wikipedia is a mix of Tarzan and *[Prince Valiant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Valiant)*.

[image: A drawing of Warlord, a character with somewhat more "savage" clothing. He is mostly naked, save for some pieces of armours, such as a helmet, a skull shaped pauldron on his right shoulder, some metallic boots, some metallic armbands, protection for his private parts and a belt, as well as a very basic torso harness.]

No idea yet for the black and white world, although it kind of fits the [film noir genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_noir), considering the settings are supposed to be in 1950s.

Also, the name of the movie is Warworld, and the main villain is [Mongul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongul), which is also a throwback to the comics, because Mongul is the lord and tyrant of a planet called [Warworld](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Warworld).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why the answer was downvoted. The question asked whether or not the worlds/settings of the movie were created solely for it, to which I answered that they're all based on existing concept. I wish I got an explanation so that I knew what could be improved.